# How I reuse trained model in DNN?

Tags: tensorflow

Everyone!

I have a question releate in trained model reusing( tensorflow ).

I have train model

I want predict new data used trained model.

I use DNNClassifier.

I have a model.ckpt-200000.meta, model.ckpt-200000.index, checkpoint, and eval folder.

but I don't know reuse this model..

plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import your graph,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt-200000.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

Then you can give input to the graph and get the output.

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")#input tensor by name    
feed_dict ={input:} #input to the model

#Now, access theoutput operation. 
op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_:0") #output tensor

print sess.run(op_to_restore,feed_dict) #get output here
```

Few things to note,

- You can replace the above code with your training part of the graph
  (*i.e* you can get the output without training).
- However, you still have to construct your graph as previously and
  only replace the training part.
- Above method only loading the weights for the constructed graph. Therefore, you have to construct the graph first.

A good tutorial on this can be found here, http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/

If you don't want to construct the graph again you can follow this tutorial, https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc

Comment: hmm, i don't use session.
ex>
m = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier()
m.train()
m.predict..