# How to reuse a trained model to perform classification - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've trained a CNN model on Tensorflow and I'd like to reuse to perform classification and test it.
This is what I'm currently doing:

```
def test(trained_model):
    # returns a iterator.get.next()
    x_test, y_test = inputs('test_set.tfrecords', batch_size=128, training_size=10000, shuffle=False, num_epochs=1)
    # get the output of the cnn
    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(AlexNet(x_test))
    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
        # Accuracy
           acc = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y_test, 1))
           acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(acc, tf.float32))

    # Initializing the variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as new_sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(trained_model)
        saver.restore(new_sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        cnt = 1
        try:
            while(True):
                new_sess.run(init)
                print(acc.eval(), cnt)
                cnt+=1

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Finished batch')
```

It seems to be working, but it's different from the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404102/how-i-reuse-trained-model-in-dnn) I've found, where people are using `graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_:0")`, and `feed_dict` which I don't understand.
Could anyone tell me if what I'm doing is right and what's the right workflow?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is right and there's no "right workflow" (tl;dr: they're logically equivalent).

When you save a model using a `Saver`, Tensorflow automatically creates for you the `.meta` and `.ckpt` files, where the  `.meta` contains the graph definition (the list of nodes and their connections) and the `.ckpt` file contains the model parameters.

`tf.train.import_meta_graph` loads in the current default graph the graph definition saved in the `.meta` file and the `restore()` call populates the graph with the set of weights of the `ckpt` file.

Clearly, if the current default graph already has the same definition that `import_meta_graph` is trying to define, the definition step is skipped.

This means that if you, before importing the meta-graph, have already defined the same graph, you can use the python variables (eg `predictions`) to refer to the nodes in the graph.

Instead, if you don't already have defined the graph, the `import_meta_graph` will define the graph for you, but you won't have any python variable ready to use.

Hence you have to extract a reference to the desired node from the graph and create a python variable to use (eg `input = graph.get_tensor_by_name("logits:0")`)